# Display all SKU combinations on Configurable Product page

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4

how do I go about displaying all possible SKU combinations on a Configurable Product page?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$simple_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct(Mage::registry('current_product'))
                            ->getUsedProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$id_to_sku = array();                           
foreach ($simple_collection  as $_item)
{
    $id_to_sku[$_item->getId()] = $_item->getSku();
}

print_r($id_to_sku);
?>
```

Hope it helps :)